# react. trying to call custom hook from onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to make a button to logout the user and move the logic to a custom hook `useLogout.js`.

Menu.js

```
import useLogout from './useLogout';
import UserContext from './UserContext';
import TokenContext from './TokenContext';

function Menu() {
    const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
    const [token, setToken] = useContext(TokenContext);

/*  some code....*/
 let button;

    if (token && token.access_token && user) {
        button = <Button onClick={useLogout}>Logout</Button>;
    } else {
        button = <Button>Login</Button>;
    }

/* some code.... */
    return(
      <Nav.Link>
          {button}
      </Nav.Link>
    )
}
```

useLogout.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState} from 'react';
import UserContext from './UserContext';
import TokenContext from './TokenContext';

export default function useLogout() {

    const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
    const [token, setToken] = useContext(TokenContext);

    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    setToken();
    setUser();
};
```

when i run this and click the button i get this error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
error in: `export default function useLogout() {
const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);`

so i tought that i was calling wrong to the function useLogout so i modified my code calling `onClick={useLogout()}`  instead of `onClick={useLogout}`
so the line looks like this:

```
button = <Button onClick={useLogout()}>Logout</Button>;
```

but then i get this error: React Hook "useLogout" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

even i tried:

```
button = <Button onClick={() => useLogout}>Logout</Button>;
```

how can i modified my code so when i click the button the function `useLogout` from `useLogout.js` is executed?

Comment: get it out of `if` statement

Comment: @marzelin but i need that condition, if the user is logged print the "logout button" otherwise the "login button"

Comment: put the active parts of that hook (setters, etc) in a function and return it from the hook and attach that function to the button

Comment: The error message is informative: _React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render_ So, take the `if` logic out as marzelin suggested - or even better encapsulate it in the `useLogout.js` export.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

what you want is probably something like this:

```js
export default function useLogout() {

    const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
    const [token, setToken] = useContext(TokenContext);

    return () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      setToken();
      setUser();
    }
};
```

/

```
const logoutCb = useLogout();

button = <Button onClick={logoutCb}>Logout</Button>;
```

Comment: it works thanks. just 2 questions: is this the right way of doing it in react? because create an extra variable instead of just type onClick=useLogout() is weird.

and why do i need to add the return() => to the funcion since we arent returning any information?

Comment: I am interested in this question as well.

Comment: What do you want to know specifically?

Comment: How do you pass an argument to the custom hook?

Comment: If it is from the onClick call action, you should do the following: onClick={() => logoutCB(parameter)}.

Comment: Anybody know why I get a "TypeError: functionNameXYZ is not a function" when I take this approach? New to React and tripping up on custom hooks :)