# What is correct way to fix this 'Invalid Hook Call' error in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

Well, i have this error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

I tried alot of different options to fix this, but i failed.

Here is my code

```
export const DataInput = () => {

    const Post = (testTitle, testText) => {
            useFirestore().collection('schedule-data').doc('test').set({
                testTitle: testTitle,
                testText: testText
            })
         }
    return(
        <Button 
           variant="primary"
           onClick={()=> Post(testTitle, testText)}>
           POST data
        </Button>
```

Deleted some of code that does not matter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289135/react-trying-to-call-custom-hook-from-onclick-event

Comment: You are using `useFirestore()` inside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks can only be called while rendering a component, so they need to be in the body of your component.

```
export const DataInput = () => {
  const firestore = useFirestore();
  const Post = (testTitle, testText) => {
    firestore.collection('schedule-data').doc('test').set({
      testTitle: testTitle,
      testText: testText
    })
  }
  // etc
}
```

Comment: Gonna try this a bit later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious, explanation available [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation))

Answer (score -1):

According to you code samle I may suggest that `testTitle, testText` available in `DataInput` in some way, thus you may create onClick handler with `useCallback`. React will create callback for use as handler, and re-create **only** when `testTitle, testText` changed.

```js
import {useCallback} from 'react';

export const DataInput = () => {
    const makePost = useCallback(() => {
      useFirestore().collection('schedule-data').doc('test').set({
        testTitle: testTitle,
        testText: testText
      })
    }, [testTitle, testText]);

    return (
    <Button
      variant="primary"
      onClick={makePost}
      {/* Avoid inline callback  declaration */}
    >
      POST data
    </Button>
    )
}
```